# Is there any open source which is similar to the menu on jsfiddle.net?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How can I create a expander menu similar to that on the left of jsfiddle, which will automatically hide all the other submenus when click on a menu?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a lot of `accordion` existing in jQuery

http://www.webdesigntunes.com/freebies/free-jquery-accordion-plugins/#.UmY7NVO19I4

http://designbeep.com/2012/02/22/36-awesome-jquery-accordion-plugins-and-tutorials/

Or directly in [jQuery Ui](http://jqueryui.com/accordion/)

Answer (score 1):

Is that what you're looking for  ?

http://jqueryui.com/accordion/